Issues with Applying SHAP PermutationExplainer to Custom Deep Learning Model with 12-Lead ECG Input
I am trying to use SHAP for interpretability in a custom deep learning model, specifically applying the PermutationExplainer() to my cardiac disease diagnosis model. The model input is a batch of 12-Lead ECG signals with the shape (5, 5000, 12).
However, I am encountering errors when attempting to compute SHAP values. Has anyone experienced similar issues when applying SHAP to deep learning models, particularly using PermutationExplainer?
Model code:
#Create a Sequential version of your model
sequential_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(shape=(5000, 12)),
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='softmax')
])

#Transfer weights from the original Functional model
sequential_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())

Code which gives the error:
explainer4 = shap.Explainer(sequential_model.predict, background_data)
shap_values = explainer4(background_data,max_evals = 10001)

The error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

It seems to fail during the SHAP explanation process. I suspect the issue might be related to how the data is being passed into PermutationExplainer, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.
Has anyone else encountered this or have suggestions on how to apply PermutationExplainer correctly in this context? Any help would be appreciated!
I tried various approaches such as:

Ensuring the background_data has the correct data type.


background_data = np.array(background_data)


Using a Smaller Background Data Size


background_data = background_data[:5]

But they did not do any good.
